# React render components from separate repositories

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a component that needs to be displayed in multiple applications throughout my company. These applications are all written in React/TypeScript and all use different repositories and the component I am working on will live in its own repository.

How can I render a component from a different repository in my application?

One idea I had was uploading the component as an npm package. Another though I had was to deploy the component elsewhere and render it as an iframe.

I am just looking for thoughts/advice on what to consider and what would be best practice.

Comment: Please may you avoid asking about advice/best practice? Instead may you share an attempt using a text-based [mcve]? Consider using npm packages.

Comment: Package it as an npm package and require it as an explicit dependency. The iframe idea seems very brittle

Comment: @evolutionxbox if this site is not to ask about help and advices, then not only it serves nearly no purpose, but you can also close the vast majority of questions. To me this question is a legit software architecte question that is not only very interesting but may also serve others with the same kind of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would forget about the iframe solution: even if you go the micro frontend route, there are much simpler approches than iframe.

In your case I would go the package route. I'd have a library project thay manages all the shared components that your company rely on and that publish an npm package that exposes all of them. After all, React components are just functions (or classes if you use the non-functional approach).

The drawbacks are:

- The library needs to be fully tested and protected against regressions. Not actually a drawback per-se - this is what we expect from every library - but it has to be kept in mind: since components are shared across multiple projects, a single regression on a minor version of the lib can have big negative impact.
- Fixing a bug found in a component is slower than fixing it if the component was handled in the application itself: you have to go through a whole release workflow of the library.

Ultimately it is worth it but keep in mind that quality is essential with this pattern: API, tests, full coverage and non-regression are fundamental as soon as we share components.

Comment: Really good points. Thanks. I think npm package will be the way to go. The other thing I am considering is condensing our existing structure into a single repository. It seems like the developers that initiated the these repositories didn't have a clear reason for separating them.

Comment: Yes, I think it also works. Mono-repository comes with other challenges but there are some very solid tools to make them work